# sqlsrv could not find driver laravel on azure

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, azure, pdo

After deploying the app, I changed my env file to match the connection credentials for the sql server which was up and already running.

There is an error when I visit the website

```
> PDOException in Connector.php line 55: could not find driver in
> Connector.php line 55 at
> PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=xxxx.database.windows.net;Database=xxxx', 'xxxx@xxxx', 'xxxxxx', array('0', '2', '0', false)) in Connector.php
> line 55
```

I tried opening the console from azure portal and write `php artisan migrate`, it showed the same error.

[image]

Anyone knows how can i manage to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you enabled the `php_sqlsrv` and `php_pdo_sqlsrv` extension on Azure? You can use `phpinfo()` to check the variables and extensions of your PHP runtime on Azure.

Be default, the DLL libraries `php_sqlsrv` and `php_pdo_sqlsrv` have been installed in the PHP ext folder on Azure, but haven't been configured in PHP runtime. So we need to configure the extensions manually:

1. Create a file named `.user.ini` at the root directory of your application on Azure.
2. Write the following content in `.user.ini`:

   ```
   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
   extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
   ```
3. Restart your application. Check the extension of `sqlsrv` and `pdo_sqlsrv` again.

## update

As the libraries `sqlsrv` and `pdo sqlsrv` for PHP 7 are available now. Please try the following to enable the sqlsrv extension for PHP 7 on Azure Web Apps:

1. Download the extension package for PHP 7 from https://github.com/Azure/msphpsql/tree/PHP-7.0, unzip for following use.
2. Follow the guide of https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-enable-extensions-in-the-default-php-runtime to upload DLL libraries and configure in PHP runtime.(by default, Azure Web App requires X86 with nts version. Please use the libraries in `msphpsql-PHP-7.0\binaries\x86` you unzip before, and use `php_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll` and `php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll`)
3. Restart the site after configuring the settings.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I am using php7 , sqlsrv extension is still not available :/

Comment: i can't my app only runs in php7. thee is no solution i think only to wait. thank you for your help gary

Comment: Sorry, I found the libraries for PHP 7 are available now. Please refer to the update.

Comment: The specific release you should use for windows is the RTW version here: https://github.com/Azure/msphpsql/releases/tag/v4.0-RTW